# Modulus on a list, doable?

Tags: python, modulus

I'm trying to create a program which checks if the number is a prime number. My idea was to use the function that the square root of the number, divided by all numbers up to the square root defines if the number is a prime or not. (I hope you understand)

Anyway, I'm trying to find a way to use modulus on every character in my list. As an example

```
Prime % List(2,sqrtPrime) =/ 0 #I know this doesnt work, just a hint how i want it to work.
```

As the error if I run this is that I cant use modulus on a list, so how do i do it?
And also, will this idea go through every character from 2-sqrtPrime?

Thanks

Comment: What is `Prime`? `List`? Your "code" is a long way from valid Python syntax.

Comment: First approximation would be a loop over the list. Then few optimizations with things like `all` and generator expressions.

Answer (score 1):

What seems the optimal way to me, would look like:

```
rng = xrange(2, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1)
is_prime = all(n % i for i in rng)
```

Main points are:

- `rng` is a generator, not a list
- expression within `(...)` is a generator as well, so no unnecessary intermediate lists are created
- `all` will stop iterating as soon as the first divisor is found, thus no extra iterations

Comment: remember you have to floor your square root or `range` will crash

Comment: What does the floor module actully do? Why is it necessary? Is it not enough with int()?

Comment: @Karl in this case, yes `int` is enough. However `math.floor(-3.1) == -4` and `int(-3.1) == -3` so that's not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that returns `True` if its argument is Prime and otherwise `False`, then run `filter` on the list.

```
import math

def isPrime(x):
    for factor in range(2,math.floor(x**0.5)+1):
        if x % factor == 0:
            # x divides evenly, so
            return False
    return True

lst = [some, numbers, go, here]

primes_in_lst = filter(isPrime, lst)
```

Or if you're against `filter` as a rule (some people contend it's unpythonic) then you can put it in a list comp.

```
primes_in_lst = [num for num in lst if isPrime(num)] # exactly equivalent
```

and technically that `isPrime` function could be a `lambda`:

```
primes_in_lst = filter(lambda x: all(x%factor for factor in range(2,math.floor(x**0.5)+1)), lst)
```

But jeebus that's ugly.

Comment: I think you hit the spot there, just what is was talking about and looking for. Just couldnt state it any good! Cheers for that